About copyright problem in creating benchmark dataset for pre-modern books
I'm a newbie so please answer me softly.
Basically I want to create a benchmark dataset in Vietnamese pre-modern books (when the context, content, dialect, grammar, aged printed quality, printing mold is very different) for OCR tasks (text recognition).
The problem is I downloaded them from internet (where some individual just uploaded and give link to some cloud drive), I just fetched one by one which has ground truth.
These books published date ranged from 1880 to 1970 and many of their publishers were gone (bankruptcy or sold or renamed or merged or private-to-nationalize). I mean the copyright here for each book is very different (because Vietnam changed political system after the war).
It's complicated than I thought since it was transitive time (Sino-Nom to Franco colonized state to South Vietnam to now), many technical troubles I solved. But suddenly ChatGPT (I asked where to published) told me to be careful with copyright problem. I don't know where to ask so I hope I can get help from here.
I really want to publish this because nobody tries it, current OCR is not good enough since Vietnamese research community don't pay attention much as Chinese or Korean did. I would like to contribute this for further research (as an effort to digitalize VNese aging books).
But with this copyright, I don't have any experience at all. Also, there're around 100 books like this, contact all of them is another painful problem. I wonder if I could publish but with a condition or an agreement that this is "research only purpose" benchmark dataset and nobody should use it as reselling or something like that.
If somebody knows how to deal with this copyright in the least effortful way, please tell me. Thank you very much.

This is a good question but it likely belongs in the legal stack exchange.

Also beware of trusting what ChatGPT says on any subject as complicated as your book copyrights. It's often wrong, and probably has a strong bias towards modern copyright rules from USA
